# Remove null values from array using Array.indexOf?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, null

I'm trying to find if there's a null value in my array without using for loops, mainly something similar to Array.indexOf. Undefined is NOT a string, it's a null value that comes up as undefined when I use console.log(ARRPREFIX)

```js
var arr = ["**", undefined, null];
if (arr.indexOf(null) > -1) {
  console.log("Should be null");
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(null), 1);
}
```

Above is my code, however it doesn't detect the undefined value, I also tried putting in "undefined" instead but that doesn't work.

Comment: `null` ≠ `undefined` ≠ `"undefined"`

Comment: You dont have an "undefined value", you have a **string** which so happens to have the characters `undefined`. It's as far from undefined as undefined can be

Comment: undefined is not the actual string undefined, it's a null value that comes up as undefined when I use console.log(ARRPREFIX) to print the array.

Comment: Just use `arr.filter(Boolean)` It should remove falsy values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out falsy values (null, undefined, etc):

```js
var array = [2, 3, null, 4, undefined, 5];
array = array.filter(Boolean);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: what about `undefined` ?

Comment: See my edited answer. Just fixed to handle undefined also

Comment: And did you notice the undefined is not actually `undefined`

Comment: I considered undefined, and not "undefined". If you want to filter out the string "undefined", it is just a matter of adjusting the filter

Comment: It's not the string undefined, but a null value/undefined value

Comment: @Mad_Questionnaire then your question is wrong/misleading

Comment: Also, is item the thing I want to filter? if I change it to null, would it filter out null values?

Comment: In filter, you pass a function that should return true only for items you want to KEEP. Both null and defined evaluates to false, so they are filtered out. Only truthy values are kept  (excluding null and undefined)

Comment: You can shorten it removing inner function to filter: `array.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Nice suggestion! Just edited my answer to use this instead

Answer (score -2):

I think those javascript array functions use loops on background anyway.

Comment: The point is I don't want to loop through my entire array and delete null/undefined values, since overtime it will get bigger so for loops just won't do.

Comment: Those functions are going to be executed anyway, how do you thing array functions work? You can't get value of it without looping trought array. Index of is going to do that anyway...